# Inputting data from one table to another

Tags: mysql

So I have a table called **CurrentCourses** like this:

```
 username   CurrrentCourseID:
   admin    1001
   admin    1002
   admin    1003
```

And another table called **PreviousCourses** with the following columns:

```
Username PrevCoursesID Grade
```

So I want to move all data from CurrentCourses into PrevCourses plus a string Grade. Assume I want grade to be 'A'.
I can move username and courses just fine using this:

```
INSERT INTO PreviousCourses(Username, PrevCoursesID)
SELECT Username, CurrentCourseID FROM CurrentCourses
WHERE USERNAME = 'admin'
```

This works fine. But if I try this:

```
INSERT INTO PreviousCourses(Username, PrevCoursesID, Grade)
SELECT Username, CurrentCourseID FROM CurrentCourses
WHERE USERNAME = 'admin',
'A'
```

It fails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it as a string in your select segment if it's not coming from the other table

```
INSERT INTO PreviousCourses(Username, PrevCoursesID, Grade)
SELECT Username, CurrentCourseID, 'A' as Grade FROM CurrentCourses
WHERE USERNAME = 'admin'
```

Comment: But your query looks for the column Grade in CurrentCourses. The column grade doesn't exist there. But I tried your query but just removed the Grade =. Instead I just put 'A' and it says column count doesn't match value count at row 1